# Laravel best practices: validations with predefined fields

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel and I start a small project to learn it. For this I have a problem and look for a good way to solve this.

I have written a validate method like in the docs and validate my forms with this function.

```
public static function validate($object, $request) {
    $object->validate($request, [
        'type' => 'in:foo,bar',
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);
}

$obj = new Job();
$obj->validate($this, $request);
[...]
$obj->save();
```

This works good, but some models have fields, that are required but mostly predefined by me in the controller. For example when I create a entry with a user_id field for the current user.

```
$obj = new Obj();
$obj->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$obj->validate($this, $request);
[...]
$obj->save();
```

The user_id isn't part of the $request object, so it wouldn't be validated.

So I can remove the `required` in the validation or define 2 different validation functions. Is there also an other possibility? Is it maybe possible to add the fields to `$request`? What is the best possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use validation scenarios in your validation method, like this:

```
public function validate($input, $scenario)
{
    switch ($scenario)
    {
        case 'create':
        case 'update':
            $rules = [
                'first_name' => 'required',
                'last_name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|email_available'
            ];
            break;

        case 'change_password':
            $rules = [
                'current_password' => 'required|check_current_password',
                'new_password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
            ];
            break;
    }

    return Validator::make($input, $rules);
}
```

Usage: `$object->validate($input, 'create');`

You also can have an array with common rules and add to it new rules based on scenario.